# Best practice for adding Resistor to PLC cabinet

Tags: resistors, plc, panel-mounting, terminal-block

My Micro-step drive and PLC need a simple resistor network between their i/o ports.The optocouplers in the stepper drive have a max input current of 15mA, while the controller needs to output at least 20mA to give valid signals. The circuit below satisfies these requirements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDHjDl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is a good way to mount these resistors in my PLC cabinet?

Are there terminal blocks that accommodate through hole resistors nicely, or would panel/chassis mount resistors be a better solution?

I have looked at some of the terminal blocks out there, but I haven't seen an elegant solution for adding through hole components. I have looked at panel mount resistors as well, but the power ratings are often much greater than I need.

Comment: Are you sure that the PLC MUST output 20 mA, or is it just capable of outputing 20 mA?  If the latter is true, then you just need a suitable series resistor to limit input current to the optocoupler.

Comment: Agreed. Give us a link and a page reference for the output specification.

Comment: Check out my [previous post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416338/using-micrologix-1400-1766-l32bxb-fet-outputs-to-control-frequency-input-to-st). It is a question about the same system regarding exactly what you both are interested in.

Comment: Something like this works too. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/phoenix-contact/2775249/2552972

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search for "**DIN rail component carrier**" throws up images such as this.

[image]

*Figure 1. A user-configurable PCB with screw terminals and DIN rail mount. Image source: Google image search.*

For just one or two resistors or diodes it's common to connect them using standard DIN terminals.

Comment: This looks really great!

Comment: I recommend that you un-accept my answer for a day or two to encourage other contributions. You'll get all sorts of ideas from them and maybe a better solution than this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I found a couple more options for this while looking for something similar:

I found this from one supplier, haven't found anyone else that makes them.

[Ocean Controls 2 x 2K2 Resistor module](https://oceancontrols.com.au/KTD-313.html?category_id=485)

[image: 2 resistor module from Ocean Controls]

As mentioned above, the various big terminal block manufacturers have options for soldering in components - for example, these are all from Phoenix Contact:
[image]

Those are [PTME 6-BE](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=3035687), [UDK 4-DUR](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2775207), [PTTB 2,5-2BE](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=3211480)

Phoenix also sell a solderless component holder that uses a spring clamp system to hold & connect through-hole components:

[image]

This replaces the blade in a disconnect terminal block - so you need 3 bits - the resistor, the component holder ([P-CO](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=303679)), and a disconnect terminal block (e.g. [ST 2,5-TG](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=3038435))